# Merge two concecutive rows into one having the same unique key in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe having 1K rows, I want to combine the rows having same Keyset Name,ID,Conc into one e.g. 
Actual Dataframe

```
ID Name Conc Val1 Val2
1  XYZ       10    0
1  XYZ       0     20
2  ABC       10    0
2  ABC       0     15
```

Converted Dataframe

```
ID Name Conc Val1 Val2
1  XYZ       10    20
2  ABC       10    15
```

Comment: Seems obvious, what's the problem?

Comment: @coldspeed I know that i need to use group by but because of the empty conc column I am unable to do so..
df.groupby(['ID','Name'],as_index=False).max() This is not able to accomplish the task

Comment: Can you try `df.groupby['ID','Name']).agg({'Val1' : 'sum', 'Val2' : 'sum'})`?